# Smarty template how to set value of textboxes based on two arrays

Tags: php, smarty, sugarcrm

I need to dynamically populate some textboxes **one array contains the labels** and the **second array contains the values** which I want to use to populate

```
Array ( [Enquiry] => Enquiry [Application Sent] => Application Sent [Application Received] => Application Received [Interview Booked] => Interview Booked [Offer Made] => Offer Made [Offer Accepted] => Offer Accepted [Deposit Paid] => Deposit Paid ) 1 

Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => 5 [6] => ) 1
```

The text boxes are created based the first array, I need to check the position in the first array and populate the value in the text box with the value from corresponding index in the second array. So enquiry will have a value 10 and offer accepted a value of 5 etc.

How do I do this in the following smarty code? I have never really worked with smarty before.

```
  <input type="hidden" id="{{if empty($displayParams.idName)}}{{sugarvar key='name'}}{{else}}{{$displayParams.idName}}{{/if}}_multiselect"
name="{{if empty($displayParams.idName)}}{{sugarvar key='name'}}{{else}}{{$displayParams.idName}}{{/if}}_multiselect" value="true">
{multienum_to_array string={{sugarvar key='options' string=true}} default={{sugarvar key='default' string=true}} assign="values"}
{$values|@print_r}
{multienum_to_array string={{sugarvar key='value' string=true}} default={{sugarvar key='default' string=true}} assign="vals"}
{$vals|@print_r} 

{foreach from=$values key=k item=item}

    {if @in_array($k, $vals)}
        {assign var=v value=true}
    {else}
        {assign var=v value=false}
    {/if}

    <input size="2" type="text" id="" name="{{if empty($displayParams.idName)}}{{sugarvar key='name'}}{{else}}{{$displayParams.idName}}{{/if}}[]" value="{ {{sugarvar key='value' string=true}}.$item }" />&#37; &nbsp;<label>{ {{sugarvar key='options' string=true}}.$item }</label><br />

{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are You creating 2 arrays? I think **creating 1 array** like below will work better for You

```
Array ( 
         [Enquiry] => '10' ,
         [Application Sent] => '', 
         [Application Received] => '',
         [Interview Booked] => '', 
         [Offer Made] => '', 
         [Offer Accepted] => '5', 
         [Deposit Paid] => '' 
     )
```

then process the array like below:-

if **$myArray** contains the above array then

```
{foreach from=$myArray key=k item=val}
   <li>{$k}: {$val}</li>
{/foreach}
```

**$k is defining the key and $val defining the value of $myArray array**

Comment: yes of course but I am not creating the arrays, I just have to use what is provided buy the system. I am basically creating a custom field in a template that combines two separate fields in the system.

Comment: Do You have only access in tpl file or also in php file?

Comment: Just for the record the system is sugarcrm and it uses version 2.6.11 of smarty